# LEFT JOIN query which updates values in the left table

Tags: postgresql, left-join

Whenever we join two tables with common names, those common names are duplicated. But what if you want to do a left join and replace values (especially NULL values)? For updating a table you can use the [MERGE operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html) but what about in a query?

The following tables are clear documentation of the desired functionality. How can we achieve this in a query? e.g.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING(date) 
                LEFT_MERGING(col2)
    -- LEFT_MERGING prefers the left-hand col2 value if there is one.
```

Table1:

```
date        | col1 | col2  
------------+------+------
'2023-08-01'|    1 |  20
'2023-08-02'|    2 | NULL
'2023-08-03'|    3 | NULL
'2023-08-04'|    4 | NULL
'2023-08-05'|    5 | NULL
'2023-08-06'|    6 | NULL
```

Table 2:

```
 date        | col2
 ------------+------
 '2023-08-03'|  22
 '2023-08-04'|  23
```

AIM:

```
date        | col1 | col2  
------------+------+------
'2023-08-01'|    1 |  20
'2023-08-02'|    2 | NULL
'2023-08-03'|    3 |  22
'2023-08-04'|    4 |  23
'2023-08-05'|    5 | NULL
'2023-08-06'|    6 | NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

With the proper logic, you can achieve the desired functionality using the `COALESCE` function and a `LEFT JOIN`. The `COALESCE` function returns the first non-NULL value in a list of expressions.

Here's how you can achieve the AIM result using a combination of `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    t1.date,
    t1.col1,
    COALESCE(t2.col2, t1.col2) AS col2
FROM
    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.date = t2.date USING(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html) function and a bit of basic machinery:

```
SELECT   date 
       , col1
       , COALESCE(table1.col2, table2.col2) AS col2
  FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 USING(date)
```

`COALESCE( x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)`   returns the first argument which is not `NULL` or returns `NULL` if all its arguments are `NULL`.